# Geodatabase Connection to Oracle Active Data Guard Standby

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

**ENVIRONMENT**

Database Server:

- Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 Single-Instance Database on Windows Server 2003 R2
- Enterprise 64-bit Oracle Active Data Guard for Oracle Database 11g R2
- ArcSDE for Oracle 11g 9.3.1 SP2 using SDELOB

Client Machine:

- Oracle Client 11.2.0.1.0 on Windows 7 Enterprise
- ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 SP2 on Windows 7 Enterprise
- ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 SP2 QIP Patch
- ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 SP2 Geodatabase Patch
- ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 SP2 Geometric Network Patch

**BACKGROUND**

I have successfully created two standby databases from my primary Oracle database; one is a physical standby (with realtime-SQL enabled) and the other is a logical standby. When attempting to connect to either of the standby databases using direct connect in ArcCatalog, I receive the following error:

Error: Operation Failed (-1)

It then occurs to me that both standby databases are running in read-only mode, which is expected when creating standby databases via Oracle Active Data Guard. After some more research, I find that it is possible to modify a standby database such that it can run in read-write mode. After modifying the standby to run in read-write mode, I am then able to make edits to the standby. Afterward, however, I was unable to resume the application of redo logs for the standby database which essentially broke the connection between my standby and my primary. This was evident after receiving a variety of Oracle errors (e.g., ORA-01665 and ORA-01153) when following the Oracle documentation for how to switch from the standby back to the primary. In essence, I wasn't able to re-link the standby and primary databases ever again such that redo logs were applied correctly from the primary to the standby.

The good news is that I *can* connect to either the logical or physical standby if I perform a Switchover within OEM 12c R3 such that the primary and standby databases swap roles. Therefore, I think it has something to do with the read-only status of the database whereby Data Guard is enabled.

After some discussion with a contact at Esri, part of the solution might reside in the SDE.SERVER_CONFIG table, specifically with the READONLY parameter.  Setting the CHAR field to TRUE and the NUM field to 1 would set the geodatabase to read-only mode (Esri's method of read only).  However, I can't change this value on the standby because it's in read-only mode according to the Oracle software.  I found out that making a geodatabase connection actually performs edits at login.  There is an Oracle package that executes a function or two which performs inserts and object creations within the database.  Setting the geodatabase to read-only mode per the method above may be the way to change this behavior but I'm still waiting for answers at the moment.

Lastly, I believe there are a list of exclusions that are needed when setting up the Active Data Guard replication for *logical* standby databases.  I'm yet to find those, though.

Has anyone used ArcSDE in conjunction with Oracle Active Data Guard?

If so, how am I able to make a geodatabase connection to the standby?

I am trying to determine the high-level proper workflow for creating a standby database and subsequently configuring the standby to receive archived redo data from the primary database (using either Redo Apply, Real-Time Apply, or SQL Apply).

Comment: Just adding your own link from GeoNet in which you've greatly expanded on this topic for others: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/88039